# How do you properly handle null values in DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, t-sql, datatables

I'm trying hard to understand the DataTables documentation, and I'm looking for examples, but I just don't get how to handle null values.

In SQL, I send a JSON string back to my JS app.  I discovered I had to use `INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES` -- so, I'm no longer missing anything in the JSON array/object.

Here's how I'm populating the table.  My `ary` is an array of objects with data like this:

```
ary = [{"Effective Date":"2001-07-01","Schedule":"UR-FUPA","Description":"High Up Dude","Calculated":"No","Base Schedule":"","Factor":null}, {...}, {...}]

$("#tblSomeTable").DataTable({
    "data": ary,
    "columns": [
        {
            "data": "Effective Date"
        },
        {
            "data": "Schedule"
        },
        {
            "data": "Description"
        },
        {
            "data": "Calculated"
        },
        {
            "data": "Base Schedule"
        },
        {
            "data": "Factor"
        }
    ],
    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": _all,
        "defaultContent": ""
    }],
    "paging": false,
    "ordering": true,
    "info": false,
    "searching": false,
});
```

So, how do I set the default content to an empty string if the cell has no data?

You can see above that I tried to use the "defaultContent" option to target all columns, but that is not working.

I always appreciate your help.  I'm not asking you to do my work, I just need an example I can understand, and your guidance in the right direction.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to specify `_all` as `string` as `target` option takes `integer` and `string` values.

So just update `columnDefs` as`

```
"columnDefs": [{
    "targets": '_all',
    "defaultContent": ""
}],
```

Your Example forked jsfiddle working demo: ***https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/5pgp2479/***

Source : [***columnDefs.targets***](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs)

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer:  (1) the quote missing around `'_all` was only part of my problem; (2) also, not shown, I was targeting the wrong table `#id`; (3) ultimately, I didn't need to specify columnDefs **at all**, so long as empty cells are included in the JSON object as either `""` or `null` via `for json path, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES `

Comment: it solved my problem, while I have several objects in my json data and sometimes one object is null, so the sub property name is missing

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is current support for setting defaultContent in columnDefs. You would need to set it per column.

Comment: I tested and found that I can do it both per column, or through columnDefs. 
 In fact, I didn't need to worry about it at all.  I found that as long as the JSON object  contained "null" or an empty empty string, it would render the table.