# Show blank cells in Laravel Datatable

Tags: laravel, datatables

I am using Datatable with Laravel. I have some null values in `User` tables of database. I would like to show them as empty in Datatable. My Datatable JavaScript code is like below.

```
var table = $('.user_table').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                "columnDefs": [{
                  "defaultContent": "-",
                  "targets": "_all"
                }],
                ajax:{
                  url:"{{ route('users.index') }}",
                  dataType: "json",
                  type:"GET",
                  headers: {
                      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                  },
                },
                columns: [
                  {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex'},
                  {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
                  {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
                  {data: 'phone', name: 'phone'},
                  {data: 'address', name: 'address'},
                  {
                    data: 'action', 
                    name: 'action', 
                    orderable: false, 
                    searchable: false
                  },
                ]
            });
```

But I am getting error `DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7`.

If I put some data in null cells then I am not getting any error.

[image]

Comment: Specify default value for all columns. This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48917064/how-do-you-properly-handle-null-values-in-datatables.

Comment: The error message you are showing us in your question says "_please see [http://datatables.net/tn/7](http://datatables.net/tn/7)_". Did you do that? Did you follow the diagnosis and resolution steps it walks you through? What happened if/when you did that? Did it help? If not, can you clarify why not?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your JSON (as formatted text) which helps us to recreate the problem you are facing? DataTables should be able to display JSON `null` values as empty cells without any specific handling/config needed.